# How to install and configure httplib2 in pycharm?

Tags: python, configuration, pycharm, httplib2

I installed httplib2 library for google in the jetbrains pycharm using project interpreter . Now on following lines it gives me errors as unresolved reference:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import run
```

How to resolve this issue? Is some configuration needed to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `File` -> `Settings` -> `Project Interpreter` . At right side you can find the current `project interpreter` of your project. Check if the the installed packages are listed there. If not install them. If they are listed then double check your `project` and the `project interpreter`. Restart the `ide`. You can also create virtual environment for your project and install the packages on them.

Answer (score 0):

After noticing that the module is already installed, both by pip and by the project interpreter, and nothing worked, this what did the trick (finaly!):

1. make sure the module is indeed installed:

   sudo pip{2\3} install --upgrade httplib2
2. locate the module on your computer:

   find / | grep httplib2

you will need to reach the place in which pip is installing the module, the path would probably look like this:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

3. get into the path specified there ,search for the module, and copy all the module files and folders into your local pycharm project environment. this will be a directory with a path like this:

   /home/your_user/.virtualenvs/project_name/lib/python2.7

this is it. note however you may need to do this multiple times, since each module may have a dependencies...